# Golang - Crypto's package function "Available()" is undefined

Tags: go, cryptography

It might be a very basic and stupid question, but I'm stuck. As I understood from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#Hash.Available), the Available() function should return `true` if the given hash function was imported. So, this code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(md5.Available())
}
```

Should produce `true` as an output. However, I get the "./main.go:10: undefined: md5.Available" error when trying to run code above. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `md5` youre using is package's identifier, what you need is "instance" of type [Hash](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#Hash):

```
import (
    "crypto"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(crypto.MD5.Available())
}
```

output:

```
false
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just found this out. Also wanted to add that the code above with output "false", since the md5 itself was not imported. If you add `crypto/md5` to your import statement, the output will be true

Comment: Just voted the other answer up because this comment wasn't integrated into the answer. Please edit answers and don't just leave such information in comments.

Comment: The question isn't about the `Available()` function and on which circumstances it returns true or false, but about confusion on how to call it. To quote the OP: *As I understood from the documentation, the Available() function should return true if the given hash function was imported* - so he already knows it and just repeated in the comment what he had already said in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`crypto.MD5.Available()`:

> Available reports whether the given hash function is linked into the
>   binary.

hash function is linked into the binary:
working sample code ( with `crypto.MD5.Available()` == `true`):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(crypto.MD5.Available()) // true

    w := md5.New()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World")
    fmt.Printf("%x \n", w.Sum(nil))
}
```

hash function is not linked into the binary:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(crypto.MD5.Available())
}
```

output:

```
false
```